# DRF: get_object in action from custom queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have ViewSet like this

```
class CustomViewSet(
    RouteActionArgumentsMixin,
    viewsets.ModelViewSet
):
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        MyModel.objects.filter(...)
```

I want to add an action in this particular ViewSet which is based on the other queryset (let's say it is based on all MyModel objects).

```
@action(
    detail=True,
    methods=['post'],
    serializer_class=OtherSerializer
)
def make_action(self, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=self.request.data, partial=True)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

How can I retrieve `self.get_object()` based on all `MyModel` objects? Can I change queryset for this particular action?

Comment: Just don't call `self.get_object()` and get the object in the method?

Comment: Thank you. How can I do that? Get pk from URL and take instance by `objects.get()`? There is also a problem with some permissions, which are checked in `get_queryset()`